# asp.net /C#: strange output when search using .contains in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

i have a repeater which and has an two search boxes one for container number and the other for custom declaration and one button, when the user search for container number it gives me expected output but when search for custom declaration the output appear duplicate as two records.

this is the code for search button:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    PortalUser p = (PortalUser)Session["userName"];



        var query = (from con in db.Containers
                     join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
                     join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
                     where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null &&
                     v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId && con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text == null ? con.cont_Name : txtContNo.Text) || con.cont_customdec.Contains(txtCust.Text == null ? con.cont_customdec : txtCust.Text)
                     select new
                     {
                         cont_name = con.cont_Name,
                         vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                         VehicleState = cust.Capt_AR,
                         vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
                         vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
                         vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
                         cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
                     }).ToList();


 rptVehl.DataSource = query;
            rptVehl.DataBind();


}
```

i think the issue in the condition:

```
con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text == null ? con.cont_Name : txtContNo.Text) || con.cont_customdec.Contains(txtCust.Text == null ? con.cont_customdec : txtCust.Text)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the `||` operator between the two `Contains` conditions should be `&&`

Comment: @IvanStoev tried to doe that but it gives me no output unless i provide two inputs.

Comment: It should work though. Except if property `.Text` never returns `null` (but empty string `""`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, i should surround the two .contain with with braces like this:

```
 (con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text == null ? con.cont_Name : txtContNo.Text) || con.cont_customdec.Contains(txtCust.Text == null ? con.cont_customdec : txtCust.Text))
```